# What does "all but" means? Rudin 3.2

Tags: real-analysis

Rudin thm 3.2 (a) $P_n$ converges to p iff every nbhd of $p$ contains ALL BUT finitely many of the terms of $P_n$

Comment: It means that that there are only a finite number of points in $P_n$ that are not in a given neighborhood.

Comment: It contains all of them, except for finitely many.

Answer (score 3):

It means everything except finitely many. So if you have 
$$x_n \in A$$
for all but finitely many $n$, then this means that 
$$\# \{n \in \mathbb{N} ~ | ~ x_n \notin A\} < \infty.$$

Answer (score 2):

Everything except finitely many.

Answer (score 1):

It means "all except", so all but finitely many means all except finitely many.